# erlang error when erlang spawning python instance, with erlport

Tags: python, concurrency, parallel-processing, erlang, runtime-error

I try to figure out how many python instance/processe I can create from erlang.

I manage to create 500 instance.
when all processe are created the cpu is near to 0%.

1 python instance take 6.2MB of ram.
400 python instance take 2.4 GB of ram.
500 python instance take 3.1 GB of ram.

when i try to create 600 python instance i got this Error:

> /usr/lib/erlang/erts-7.0/bin/child_setup: error while loading shared
>   libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: Error 24
>                                         ** exception error: no match of right hand side value {error,
>                                                          {invalid_python,"/usr/bin/python"}}
>        in function  spawn_python:spawn_python/2 (spawn_python.erl, line 10)

theoretically i need 6.2MB*600 = 3.7 GB of free ram (i got them).

Here is the code i use.
it need erlport : http://erlport.org/downloads/

%% how i test it

> spawn_python:spawn_python(100).
>   spawn_python:spawn_python(100).
>   spawn_python:spawn_python(100).
>   spawn_python:spawn_python(100).
>   spawn_python:spawn_python(100).
>   spawn_python:spawn_python(100).
>   ERROR here

```
%%%%%%%% spawn_python.erl  %%%%%%%%%%%%
-module(spawn_python).
-export([spawn_python/1, spawn_python/2]).

%% spawn N python process
spawn_python(N) -> spawn_python(N, []).

spawn_python(0, PyProcPids) ->
    PyProcPids;
spawn_python(N, PyProcPids) ->
    {ok, PyPid} = python:start(),
    PyProcPid = spawn(fun() -> python_loop(PyPid) end),
    io:format("Started Erlang/Python process -- PyProcPid: ~p~n", [PyProcPid]),
    spawn_python(N - 1, [PyProcPid | PyProcPids]).

python_loop(PyPid) ->
    receive
        {stop, From} ->
            python:stop(PyPid),
            From ! ok
    end.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: solved with the help of someone from irc, ulimit -n 2048 (increase the fd limit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each spawned port needs some pipes to communicate with. Each pipe uses file descriptor (two of them but one is closed soon) and there is a limit how much file descriptors you can have opened. The number of maximum opened file descriptors is set by underlining OS (see `ulimit` syscall defined in POSIX.1-2001 or `ulimit` command of shell for unix like systems).